# Add Sitecore Package to source control

Tags: unicorn, packages

I'm trying to add a Sitecore Hotfix (https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/hab14a1l671cly284pe15io20q0bzayz) to our source control. Since we have integrated Unicorn with our solution, just adding the package would not be enough. When a new dev pull the the code from repo and syncs Unicorn, the package should be installed.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but there are no items in the hotfix, correct? So you can just include files from the hotfix in your source control?

Comment: I will try that. Thank you @MarekMusielak